# get "..." continuation for white-space nowrap style

Tags: css

I am applying white-space: nowrap successfully on a piece of text. I am wondering whether it is possible to get a standard "..." at the end of the piece of text IF it is truncated by the nowrap style. Is this something CSS can take care of? Or do I need javascript?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox (and possibly a few others) support:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

but it's not cross-browser by any means.  In order to get something cross-browser you need to use javascript.  One way I've done this in the past is:

```
<div class="text">
    text goes here
    <div class="ellipsis">...</div>
</div>

.text {
    position : relative;
}

.text .ellipsis {
    display : none;
}
.text.long .ellipsis {
    display    : block;
    position   : absolute;
    right      : 0px;
    background : #FFF;
}
```

then your js is simply something like this (using jQuery):

```
$( '.text' ).each( function(){
    var $this = $( this );
    $this[ ( $this.width() > $this.outerWidth() ) ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]
        ( 'long' );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming browser support, it may not work for another seemingly unrelated reason.
Preconditions: your text content is inside a containing block whose style is
`overflow:hidden`, `whitespace:nowrap` and `text-overflow:ellipsis`
My observation has been, the *position* property of that containing block must be "relative". The ellipses don't show if its *absolutely* positioned, the text simply gets clipped.

the answer here nails it
[absolute vs relative position width & height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height)