# Why does absolutely positioned div change width when making it relatively positioned?

Tags: html, css, width, css-position

I have a div that shows some text and is absolutely positioned on a page. While it is absolutely positioned the div is just large enough to show the text it contains. When I add an inline style to that div to change it to be relatively positioned, the width of the div suddenly expands to take up 100% of the page...

I used the Chrome dev tools to toggle the relative position on/off. Turning it off causes the width to be correct, turning it back on causes the div to expand. It is an inline style so there isn't any CSS class or selector that is changing the width on me.

I experience the same issue in Firefox. Removing `position: relative` in Firebug causes the width to shrink back down to be just wide enough to fit the text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Position Relative vs Position Absolute?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10426497/position-relative-vs-position-absolute)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height

Comment: @sandeep thanks for the links.  Is there any way to get a relatively positioned element to size based off its content instead though?

Comment: you can give float, display:inline or display:inline-block to your DIV

Comment: @sandeep inline-block worked perfectly.  Thanks man.  If you post it as an answer I'll accept it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want **relative** position DIV take his content width then  you can give `float`, `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` to your DIV

Answer (score 0):

could you please post the HTML and CSS, and I could have a look at it..
Meanwhile you might wanna have a look at 
[Position an HTML element relative to its container using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css)
and see if that could possibly help you?

Answer (score 0):

to change size as content grows/shrinks use something like:

```
<div style="min-height:30px;max-height:300px;">
```

Which will mean it'll vary between 30 and 300 px depending on content

or

```
<div style="min-height:30px;height:auto;">
```

which will vary between 30px and as big as its container will allow (so forever, essentially)