# CSS rounded corners div, footer placement position with "absolute"

Tags: css, html, position, width, absolute

I'm trying to create rounded corners  with a header and a footer.  I was able to force the header to be on top, but I don't understand why I can't force to footer to be at the bottom.

In fact, position absolute; bottom:0; does that but my footer in only the lenght of the text.  When I add width:100%;, the footer becomes larger then the  ???

Here you can see my code:  http://jsfiddle.net/fleduc/GN9q5/

Answer (score 2):

You set `left: 0` and `right: 0`, not `width: 100%;` - see test http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/GN9q5/3/

You might also want to read this http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201112/the_difference_between_widthauto_and_width100/

It's true that you have absolute positioning here and `width: auto` won't do the trick in this case, but you have to understand that `width: 100%` means the *width of the container **without** paddings and borders* (unless you use `box-sizing: border-box`)

Answer (score 1):

You have specified the div's width in px, so can you just specify the footer's width in px? Example: http://jsfiddle.net/GN9q5/4/

Comment: Ignore my answer, Ana got the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Only change this css and it is gonna work ;-)

```
.rcs .ftr {                        
        margin:110px 0 0 0; 
        font-size:1.2em; 
        padding:5px 0px 5px 10px;        
        border-bottom-left-radius: 0.35em;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 0.35em;
        border-top:1px solid #AAAAAA;
    }
```

See the test http://jsfiddle.net/GN9q5/5/

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements are no longer part of the layout. They have no idea how big the parent element is, so you have to set the width to a static value.

Answer (score 0):

You must set your `width` with a absolute value and calculate the padding.

For exemple:

```
If you have a width of 960px and a padding of "5px", your with must be 950px.

You SHOULD remove it for reason that I don't exactly know.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/*footer*/
.rcs .ftr {                        
    margin:0; 
    font-size:1.2em; 
    padding:5px 5px 5px 10px;
    position: absolute; 
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 385px;          
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.35em;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.35em;
    border-top:1px solid #AAAAAA;
}
```

You have the container width set to 400px. Left & right padding = 15px, so subtract that and set your width at 385px.

More info: [absolute vs relative position width & height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height)

Also, make sure to close all of your declarations.