# CSS Margin and Absolute property

Tags: css, margin, css-position

I want to use margin in my code, but I have some problems.
Please look at:

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="inner1">
    Margin not coming from top (not absolute)
</div>

<div id="inner2">
    Div has absolue prop
</div>
```

​

And the CSS code is:

```css
#outer {
    margin: 100px;
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    widht: 400px;
}

#inner1 {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

#inner2 {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

​

1. I am not able to understand why setting position to absolute is
   restricting width of `#inner2` div.
2. Since `#inner1` div does not have absolute property, it is not having
   margin from top. I can't understand this. Please explain.

Here is output: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/blunderboy/C7dE2/1/)

Comment: What exaclty is the problem? What is your expected outcome?

Comment: I expected that my inner1 div should have margin from top as I specified in CSS. But I got something different. Using absolute property fixed this So I wanted to know why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ques1: I am not able to understand why setting position to absolute is restricting width of inner2 div.

setting position to absolute of inner2 div, gets the width auto so as long as text.
setting position to relative of inner2 div, gets the width of outer div.

So if you want absolute positioning, set also the width of inner2 div.

Ques2: Since inner1 div does not have absolute property, it is not having margin from top. I can't understand this. Please explain.

from the document flow, your inner div never know it is inside some other div (outer), setting border or position to absolute of outer div fix this.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C7dE2/20/

Comment: Hey abhinav, Thanks for your answer. I understood completely the answer of Q1. Can you please explain by saying from document flow inner div never knows it is inside outer div but according to document flow inner div comes in outer div and moreover, why setting border of outer div solves this problem ? please point me to some link atleast...BTW thanks a lot.

Comment: @blunderboy, actually this is the case of Collapsing Margin. Here are some links : http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/collapsingmargins, http://www.researchkitchen.de/blog/archives/css-autoheight-and-margincollapsing.php, http://www.seifi.org/css/understanding-taming-collapsing-margins-in-css.html

Answer (score 1):

setting 
`position:absolute` removes the element in question from the normal flow of the document structure. So unless you explicitly set a width it won't know how wide to be. you can explicitly set width if that is the effect you're after..

see this

[absolute vs relative position width & height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height)

Answer (score 0):

You should use green div's `padding-top` property - `#inner1` with `margin-top` set on high value only pushes the whole `#outer` further down!