# Why does positioning effect div width?

Tags: html, css

I was fiddling with my web-app to try and get a div to wrap around some p elements.  The structure looks like this, i.e. pseudo-code ...

```
<div id='outer'>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>
</div>
```

What I found is that if I set the outer div to

```
position:absolute;
```

instead of

```
position:relative
```

that the div would correctly wrap around only the p elements.

Otherwise it would extend all the way to the very right of the page, and I had previously had to set the width manually.

What is governing this behavior?

Also, the p tags use

```
display:inline
```

and the containing div just uses the default display.

This CSS below works well in my app.

```
// outer div

#mi_control {
    position: absolute;
    left: 580px;
    top: 660px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

// p elements

.menu_bottom {
    margin-left: 18px;
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Any CSS you could give us to help determine the problem?

Comment: added in css, there is no problem, I'm just asking why things work this way, i.e. what governs the behavior...

Comment: you set the top and left so that's why it is pushed to the bottom right, but it will still wrap around your p tags

Comment: Duplicate question for - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behaviour is governed by the spec. Absolute positioned elements have dedicated rules about how widths are calculated: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue..

I [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height):

**Question**: *relative div takes 100% width automatically but absolute div only takes content width. why?*

**Answer**: Setting `position:absolute` removes the element in question from the normal flow of the docment structure. So unless you explicitly set a width it won't know how wide to be. you can explicitly set `width:100%` if that is the effect you're after.

Answer (score 1):

By default, a `div` element is set to `display: block;`. Block elements will be 100% of the width of the parent element.

When you set an element to `position: absolute;` it takes it out of the document flow and the element is no longer sized according to the parent element. It can mess with your layout though.

My recommendation is to set the `div` element to `display: inline-block;` - this will make it sized as per its contents, but will not remove it from the flow of the document.

```
#outer
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what rules governing this behavior but what you observed is the right behavior and is consistent across all browsers. A DIV takes minimum width when its position is set to absolute or fixed; otherwise it takes full available width.

Answer (score 1):

The default value for `width` for a `div` element is `auto`.

This means that it will take up the full with of the available space, or more if the contents forces it to. If you use `position: absolute` however, you take the element out of the document flow. As there is nothing that it can relate to as the full width any more, it will use the width that the contents forces it to use.

Answer (score 0):

Once it is set to absolute, it is taken out of the normal flow of content. Absolutely positioned elements always appear in the top left corner, unless otherwise specified. The element will also shrink to be only as big as it has to, because that's how `position:absolute` works

`div`s naturally have a width of 100%, so that is why you have to set the width manually. Relatively positioned elements behave almost identically to statically positioned elements. The only difference is how they can be moved

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are seeing but even if your div is positioned absolutely, it will STILL wrap your P tags

http://jsfiddle.net/8MSDH/

you are seeing it at the bottom right because you set your top and left

```
left: 580px;
top: 660px;
```