# How to make absolute div assume content's width?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following peace of code - http://jsfiddle.net/QkYvs/2/

```
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="childOne">
            <div id="childTwo"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

`#childTwo` is wrapping its text to the `#parent` width. How can I make #childTwo's width to be its **content's width**?

Comment: See [absolute vs relative position width & height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height)

Comment: It is not possible to make an absolutely positioned element assume the size of its contents. Do you want to use a wrapper element to simulate it? You may also be interested in CSS3 flexbox, if you don't care about older browsers.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/QkYvs/5/)