# How do i make wrapper div correctly wrap divs inside of it?

Tags: html, css

look, here are my html and css.

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheets2.css" />
    </head>        
        <body>
            <div id="wrapper">
                <div id="cont1"></div>
                <div id="cont2"></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

css:

```css
*{
        border:none;
    }
    #wrapper{
        display:inline-block;
        background-color:lightcyan;
        position:absolute;
        top:200px;
        left:300px;
        background-color:lightyellow;
        border:1px solid green;
        }
    #cont1{
        position:absolute;
        width:100px;
        height:50px;
        background-color:red;
    }
    #cont2{
        position:absolute;
        width:50px;
        height:100px;
        background-color:red;
    }
```

1. How to make the wrapper div wrap these rectangles so it would have 100x100 size?
   note that it's undesirable to define the size of wrapper directly (height/width) because later sizes of inner divs may be modified

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you want? The inner divs will have to overlap if you want the holder div to be 100x100 - http://jsfiddle.net/timspqr/9B5x6/

Comment: Thank you for the question! It's ok to have them overlapped, I just want to use minimal number of height/width/position definitions. The border must be 100x100 and lower right quarter of wrapper should not be hidden under cont divs.

Comment: Ok, then it looks like @nevermind has your solution

Answer (score 2):

This will fix problem, but i had to set position of inner elements to: relative.

```
*{
    border:none;
}
#wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:300px;

    border:1px solid green;
    }
#cont1{
    position:relative;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
#cont2{
    position:relative;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:-50px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

Fiddle: **http://jsfiddle.net/9TZZ9/**

Edit> more about problem -> [absolute vs relative position width & height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height)

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4LbD/6/)

```
#wrapper{
 display:inline-block;
     position:absolute;
     top:200px;
     left:300px;
     background-color:lightyellow;
     border:1px solid green;
    }
#cont1{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:red;
}
#cont2{
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}
```