# How do I make row of div on top of parent div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

How do I place a row of div (which has 3 columns of image) on top of parent div (image) . I am using Bootstrap 5. Previously I used to do `postition: absolute`. The problem here is that the row overflow is being hidden. I have tried `overflow: visible` too. Below down is the code sample and the result i am getting.
Thank you for any kind of help.

```css
.accomplishments{
  background: url("https://picsum.photos/1000/600");
  width: 100%;
  height: 40rem;
  background-size: cover;
  margin-top: 12rem;
  position: relative;
}

.project-tray{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow-y:visible ;  
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
  <div class="container" >
    <h1 class="">Accomplishments</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid  accomplishments mb-5 ">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row project-tray ">
        <div class="col " >
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/301" class="img-fluid " alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/302" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/303" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

here are attached images of output:

[The output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2JXn.png)

[Expected output (figma)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8wIB.png)

Comment: Can't find the container in your HTML where "Accomplishment" is visible as the heading. Please share it too.

Comment: hello Samir, there is no problem with ```<h1>Accomplishments</h1>``` . The issue here is that overflow row is beinng hidden somehow. I have updated the images.

Comment: I understood that. But in order to provide you a solution, we need an appropriate and complete structure. If you can create a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/) that would be best.

Comment: Hello Samir, I have added appropriate structure of code for that section. Thanks for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8wIB.png is this your expected output?

Comment: Yes ! To overlap that row (which has column of 3 image) over background.

Comment: I just added height to the accomplishment container and it's working fine. Check this https://jsfiddle.net/6nxe29fL/2/

Comment: Hello Samir ! Thank you for your Help. It seemed to work.

Answer (score 0):

In general, it is better practice to "avoid" position absolute for such a simple layout (position absolute Breaks the [normal flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout) + [collapse height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896265/position-absolute-box-causes-container-to-collapse)). By `negative margin` it is very easy to create this overlap (And keep the normal flow).

Snippet (Same as your desire layout solve only by one line of custom CSS):

```css
.negative-margin{
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 class="">Accomplishments</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid  accomplishments mb-5 ">
    <div class="container" >
      <div class="row project-tray ">
        <div class="col " >
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/201/300" class="img-fluid " alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/202/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="col">
          <img src="https://picsum.photos/203/300" class="img-fluid" alt="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img class="img-fluid negative-margin" alt="Responsive image" src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1080">
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a little changes in the bootstrap structure and shifted the class `accomplishments` from `container-fluid` class to `col-12` class. Also added `margin-top: 200px !important;` that was missing in your stylesheet.css `.accomplishments`

```css
.accomplishments {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/600);
  width: 100%;
  height: 36rem !important;
  margin-top: 200px !important;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

.project-tray {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  overflow-y: visible;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<main>
  <div class="container heading">
    <h1 class="text-center pt-5">Accomplishments</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 accomplishments">
        <div class="row project-tray ">
          <div class="col ">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/301" class="img-fluid " alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/302" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col">
            <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/303" class="img-fluid" alt="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm new to web-development but I think you should try to delete the `top: 0%;` property to see if it makes change.