# Position absolute break parent

Tags: html, css, forms

I would like to centre `.login` inside `body`. Currently everything looks as desired, however if I inspect it, I can see that is not actually in `body`'s area:

[image]

I could resolve it with:

```
.login {
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

But that will break the body. How do I fix this while keeping the element in the normal work flow?

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: Anyway, I guess the accepted answer is acceptable but the final result's still turdish. Unless you really need archaic browser support, I'd go with something like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yYVgQB?editors=010.

Comment: Flexbox is good for centering vertically and horizontally: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this solve your problem?

```
html,body,.login{
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
}
```

The reason `height:100%` does not work without `position: absolute;` is because the parent of `.login` does not have 100% of the page. It would only have 100% the height of `body` which is very small: it acts as the same way default `position:static` does. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5324642/4907552) gives slightly more detail .

Comment: Get it! Thanks Jaunt, not it work!

Comment: it's funny that visually speaking is perfect, but the wrong lines behind bother me.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:

```
html, body { height: 100%; }
.login { height: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need  to use position:absolute, Use margin:0 auto instead of it

```
.login {
   width: 360px;
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Not using absolute positioning at all is a much better answer.

Comment: @Shikkediel, none of the answers posted here use position absolute.  But this is the only answer that *doesn't* solve the problem. demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EVNZPY

Comment: That's because the superfluous style on `.login_box` hasn't been removed.

Comment: Understood. But I don't see how this answer addresses that code, which wasn't the referenced `position: absolute` in the question. If this answer was referring to your `.login_box` rule,  it should be explained in the answer.

Comment: And i want center in the vertically and horizontally, so i cant use margin 0 auto.

Comment: Agreed the post isn't very explanatory but '*dont need to use position:absolute*' was a key phrase I didn't see elsewhere (to me it included the conclusion I had drawn about `.login-box`). The need for vertical centering had escaped me, don't think there's a way around absolute positioning there. But a slicker approach, yes.