# Why element with relative position's width keeps maximised, even if it has no childs?

Tags: html, css

I have a "message" element which should be resized if text doesn't fit its width with some limits(just like in messengers).

```css
.message  {
    position: relative;
    color:white;
    background:#182533;
    border-radius:10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    top: 40px;
    left: -10px;
    max-width: 320px;
    min-width: 70px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
      <div class="message">
      </div>
```

Why it still gets max width even if it's empty?

How it looks like:
[image: How it looks like]

How it should look like:
[image: How it should look like]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [absolute vs relative position width & height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323177/absolute-vs-relative-position-width-height)

Comment: using display:table is better than the below answer (more support)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this using `width: fit-content;` as shown in the snippet:
[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

```css
.message {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  background: #182533;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  top: 40px;
  left: -10px;
  width: fit-content; /*added fit-content here */
  max-width: 320px;
  min-width: 70px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css" />

<body>
  <div class="message">1-2-3-4-5-6-7</div>
  <div class="message">1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18-19-20-21-22-23-24-25</div>
  <div class="message">1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14-15-16-17-18</div>
  <div class="message">1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-10-11-12-13-14</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```